# Unique row per ID with multiple records in different columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables with different product usage info regarding unique IDs, and I'm trying to get a table with one single line per month per ID with all the product usage info.

| month | id | prod1_usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 001 | 300 |
| 2021-02-01 | 001 | 400 |
| 2021-01-01 | 002 | 100 |
| 2021-02-01 | 002 | 50 |

| month | id | prod2_usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 001 | 600 |
| 2021-02-01 | 001 | 880 |
| 2021-01-01 | 002 | 150 |
| 2021-02-01 | 002 | 10 |

The result I wanna get is:
| month | id | prod1_usage | prod2_usage |
|:----: |:------:|:------:| :-----:|
| 2021-01-01  | 001    | 300 | 600 |
| 2021-02-01  | 001    | 400 | 880 |
| 2021-01-01  | 002    | 100 | 150 |
| 2021-02-01  | 002    | 50 | 10 |

I tried creating one column for usage in general, and another one for usage_type so I could pivot it later, but it didn't work (product2 usage didn't show up)...

SELECT

```
    month,
    id,
    CASE WHEN prod1_usage IS NOT NULL THEN prod1_usage
         WHEN prod2_usage IS NOT NULL THEN prod2_usage
         END AS usage,
    CASE WHEN prod1_usage IS NOT NULL THEN 'product 1'
         WHEN prod2_usage IS NOT NULL THEN 'procut 2'
         END AS prod_type,
    FROM product1_base a
         LEFT JOIN product2_base b ON a.id=b.id AND a.month = b.month
```

Could someone hel pme out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just join two tables:

```
with prod1_table as (
    select date '2021-01-01' as month, '001' as id, 300 as prod1_usage union all 
    select '2021-02-01', '001', 400 union all
    select '2021-01-01', '002', 100 union all
    select '2021-02-01', '002', 50
),
prod2_table as (
    select date '2021-01-01' as month, '001' as id, 600 as prod2_usage union all 
    select '2021-02-01', '001', 880 union all
    select '2021-01-01', '002', 150 union all
    select '2021-02-01', '002', 10
)
select month, id, prod1_usage, prod2_usage
from prod1_table join prod2_table using (month, id)
```

[image]